# How to implement specific OrderBy using expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

Try to implement custom linq query to order dataset by any field (first take rows, which field is equal to the search string, then take all others). 
Final query should be like this:

```
    source.OrderBy(p => p.Phone == "1234567")
```

Code:

```
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortPropertyOrder.FieldName.ToString());
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    string methodName = sortPropertyOrder.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Type[] typeArguments = new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType };
    object fieldValue = Convert(property.PropertyType, sortPropertyOrder.FieldValue);

    Expression equalExp = Expression.Equal(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(fieldValue));
    Expression finalExpression = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(equalExp, parameter));
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, typeArguments, source.Expression, finalExpression);
    IQueryable<T> query = source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
```

As a result, I have an exception: No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Although I created more simple query(source.OrderBy(p => p.Phone))

```
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortPropertyOrder.FieldName.ToString());
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    string methodName = sortPropertyOrder.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Type[] typeArguments = new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType };
    object fieldValue = Convert(property.PropertyType, sortPropertyOrder.FieldValue);
Expression finalExpression = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter));
MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, typeArguments, source.Expression, finalExpression);
    IQueryable<T> query = source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
```

It works fine.
What's wrong with first query?

Comment: Does `source.OrderBy(p => p.Phone == "1234567")` actually work when coded?

Comment: You have to use `source.OrderByDescending(p => p.Phone == "1234567")`, otherwise all other numbers come first. I remember this by translating `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`.

Comment: Michael, yes. source.OrderBy(p => p.Phone == "1234567") pass when hardcoded. Tim, thanks. But now I want it at least doesn't throw exception:)

Comment: Oh, I understand! I pass as type parameters 

         Type[] typeArguments = new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType };

Where PropertyType - type of field. But 

         p.Phone == "1234567"
is bool parameter, so it should be 

        Type[] typeArguments = new Type[] { type, typeof(bool) };
Thanks!